# Jackson Serializer not invoked in Quarkus

Tags: java, json, jackson, quarkus

I use the MicroProfile REST Client in Quarkus and have declared quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson as dependency. For the invocation I need run my own code to serialize my data into JSON. I've built a custom serializer extending StdSerializer and registered it via ObjectMapperCustomizer.

I've followed the instructions in this documentation:

- https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-json
- https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/15018

But my code is never invoked. The code in my ObjectMapperCustomizer in run and the constructors of my serializer are run, but the serialize methhod is never invoked.

```
public class HighlightSerializer extends StdSerializer<Highlight> { 
    public HighlightSerializer() {
        this(null);
        System.out.println("constuctor");
    }
  
    public HighlightSerializer(Class<Highlight> t) {
        super(t);
        System.out.println("constuctor");
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Highlight value, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        System.out.println("serialize");
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("niklas", "niklas");        
    }
```

```
@Singleton
public class RegisterCustomModuleCustomizer implements ObjectMapperCustomizer {
    @Override
    public int priority() {
        return MINIMUM_PRIORITY; 
    }

    public void customize(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        System.out.println("customize");
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(Highlight.class, new HighlightSerializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);
    }
}
```

Here are pointers to my code:

- Desired JSON that needs to be created with a variable field name: https://github.com/nheidloff/question-answering/blob/299c9131310d5cbfd8fe3620a07738f973852c64/service/src/main/java/com/ibm/question_answering/elasticsearch/AskElasticService.java#L129
- Serializer that is not invoked: https://github.com/nheidloff/question-answering/blob/299c9131310d5cbfd8fe3620a07738f973852c64/service/src/main/java/com/ibm/question_answering/elasticsearch/HighlightSerializer.java#L21
- Attempt to register the serializer: https://github.com/nheidloff/question-answering/blob/299c9131310d5cbfd8fe3620a07738f973852c64/service/src/main/java/com/ibm/question_answering/elasticsearch/RegisterCustomModuleCustomizer.java#L18

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks

**Update May 15th:**

I've simplified the code. The issue is related to the REST Client. The same serialization code works in a REST endpoint, but not when invoking another REST API. So the issue is not related to using different serializers together and not a basic issue in my code.

https://github.com/nheidloff/quarkus-stackoverflow-76228719

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not completely sure about that, but empty ctor should call `this(Highlight.class)` to made serializer works

Comment: I tried this same thing on some example code and it worked just fine. See https://github.com/geoand/quarkus/tree/so-76228719

Comment: Thanks @geoand and Luca. I've tried more variations but cannot get it to work in my setup. Simple samples work, but there might be a conflict with other serializers in my code (see below). How can I debug which serializers are registered and in which order? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure honestly. Whenever I have had such issues, I had to debug Jackson code.

Comment: @geoand I've simplified the code. The issue is related to the REST Client. The same serialization code in a REST endpoint, but not when invoking another REST API. https://github.com/nheidloff/quarkus-stackoverflow-76228719 Could you please help? Or should I submit a Quarkus issue?

Answer (score 1):

I created a sample app using your code and it's functioning properly. https://github.com/bgizdov/quarkus-reactive-jackson-serializer

One modification to make is adding "jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();" before writing fields in the serialize method.

```
  @Override
  public void serialize(Highlight value, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider provider)
      throws IOException {
    System.out.println("serialize");
    jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
    jsonGenerator.writeStringField("foo_bar", "fooobar");
    jsonGenerator.writeStringField("niklas", "niklas");
  }
```

The endpoint http://localhost:8080/hello/highlight returns:

```
{
    "foo_bar":"fooobar",
    "niklas":"niklas"
}
```

If your project is not working, consider the following:

- Check if you have another Jackson object mapper customizer.
- Make sure the object mapper is not deregistered.
- Check logs if the bean is not removed from the project as unused, to prevent this try adding "@Unremovable".

Here is my log:

```
customize
constuctor
constuctor
__  ____  __  _____   ___  __ ____  ______ 
 --/ __ \/ / / / _ | / _ \/ //_/ / / / __/ 
 -/ /_/ / /_/ / __ |/ , _/ ,< / /_/ /\ \   
--\___\_\____/_/ |_/_/|_/_/|_|\____/___/   
2023-05-13 03:07:15,961 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) code-with-quarkus 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 2.16.7.Final) started in 1.340s. Listening on: http://localhost:8080
2023-05-13 03:07:15,965 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Profile dev activated. Live Coding activated.
2023-05-13 03:07:15,965 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Installed features: [cdi, resteasy-reactive, resteasy-reactive-jackson, smallrye-context-propagation, vertx]
serialize
```

Comment: Thanks Borislav! It works in your little sample, but not in my case. I use other customizers. How can I make sure object mapper is not deregistered? Adding @Unremovable didn't help. Is there a way to debug this?

Comment: @NiklasHeidloff, perhaps something else is preventing the mapper from working. Check the logs for anything suspicious or start removing parts of your code one by one to identify when it starts working.

Answer (score 1):

Au, this is embarrassing. I simply forgot to create the object. Can't make this up.

```
output.highlight = new Highlight();
```